# Adjusting Div position

Tags: javascript, prototype

I have a icon with onmouseover event handler.

On mouseover it displays a table.
the Icon is at the right site of the screen.
If the table is small, it will be displayed within visible area. But if the the table is wide enough then only a part of the table is visible. One have to scroll to right to see the rest of the table.

What would be the solution to display it. I mean if the table will go 200px out of the visible area, then it should
moved 200px to left.

The table is displayed within an absolutlty positioned DIV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The div.left + div.clientWidth should be less than document.body.clientWidth. In other words, the furthest to the right (max value of div.left) on the screen your div can be can be calculated as:

```
document.body.clientWidth - div.clientWidth
```

Give or take a pixel or two.